# Passing a global pointer through multiple files for an interrupt routine

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, interrupt

I have two questions. The first one being is it a good idea to have an interrupt routine in a separate file from your main (In a file where the other functions are defined)?

The second one is, how do i pass a global pointer from different files? To make things easier for myself the pointer is "pointing" to the address of a global variable.

*File 1 mylib.c*

```
unsigned char b;
unsigned char e;    //global variables used for the interrupt routine
unsigned char *bp =&b;
unsigned char *ep = &e;
```

*File 2 mylib.h*

```
extern unsigned char e;
extern unsigned char b;
extern unsigned char *ep;
extern unsigned char *bp;
```

*File 3 main.c*

```
#include "mylib.h"
use (e);
use (b);
use (*ep);
use (*bp);
```

it states that pointers aren't defined when they are?
I didn't find too much help on the two questions asked here so that's why i posted it, it will be interesting to find the answer.

Compilation report :

```
10 371 Specifier needed main.c
10 393 'use ' Identifier redefined main.c 
11 371 Specifier needed main.c
11 393 'use ' Identifier redefined main.c
```

Comment: Huh? If the pointer, or the variable, or both, is global, why would you want to pass it anywhere? You already have access from everywhere, by definition.

Comment: `#include mylib.h` --> `#include "mylib.h"` Also, show your compilation statement.

Comment: i've posted the compilation report and in my actual file i didn't forget to put the quotations, just forgot to put them here

Comment: You should rather ask yourself _why_ do i pass a global pointer from different files. The need to do this originates from poor program design.

Comment: If you refuse to answer the question than don't post a reply. 
The need for a global function is fundamental in PIC16F877A, if you want to use a variable in its interrupt routine and allow that variable to be incremented you need to use a global variable otherwise its value will be lost. 
The interrupt routine can't be called in the main function because the PIC will not function as intended with the LCD and passing an argument through the interrupt function will also cause problems with the LCD and therefore you need a global variable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it a good idea to have an interrupt routine in a separate file from your main (?)

This is not a requirement of C but an organizational issue of code.  Yes it is good to segment source code into logical groups.

Putting the interrupt service routine (ISR) and its related functions and variable in a seperate file is a good idea.

> how do i pass a global pointer from different files?

A global identifier (variable, object, function) is accessible to all files as it is *global*.  The trick is, does a particular .c file know of it?  By including `#include "mylib.h"` in `main.c`, that code is made aware of the identifiers given their *declarations* like `extern unsigned char *bp;`.

Also consider:

1) `unsigned char b, e;` do not need to be in the global space as other *.c files can access them through `unsigned char *bp` and `unsigned char *ep`.  See [information hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding)

2) The names `bp, ep` are short and likely to collide with other code.  Recommend a prefix that hints to their "home".

3) The pointers likely should be constant and point to `volatile` data as they are part of an ISR.

```
    // mylib.h
    extern volatile unsigned char * const mylib_ep;
    extern volatile unsigned char * const mylib_bp;

    // mylib.c
    static volatile unsigned char b;
    static volatile unsigned char e;
    volatile unsigned char * const mylib_bp = &b;
    volatile unsigned char * const mylib_ep = &e;

    // main.c
    #include "mylib.h"
    // do not use (e);
    // do not use (b);
    use (*mylib_ep);
    use (*mylib_bp);
```

> it states that pointers aren't defined when they are?

The pointers are *declared* in `mylib.h`.  The pointers are *defined* in `mylib.c`.

---

From a design standpoint, I would not let other files access the data as above.  Instead I would create a *get* and *set* function.  I assume these 2 variables need to be read/written in an *atomic* fashion: both read/written together without a chance of the ISR being called during the get/set.

```
void mylib_b_e_get(char *b, char *e);
void mylib_b_e_set(char b, char e);
```

---

Compilation reports on `use` reflects that the pseudo-code function `use()` is not yet declared nor defined.